# Numerical maximization

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I am facing a numerical maximization problem with constraints.
Using `Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 3}, AccuracyGoal -> 2` often does not find the global maximum. I think this happens in many cases as this method runs into problems of finding initial values.
`"Nelder-Meat"` and `"DifferentialEvolution"` also had their problems.

(`F[x]` is an estimation of a normal distributed function)

```
A = 1*10^4 ; b = 1/4; delta = 0; a = 20; j = 100;

K[x] := 0.579259709439103` + 
    x (7.821505478148196`*^-7 + 
       x (-1.5613375172341804`*^-13 + 
          x (-5.021167974758985`*^-19 + 
             x (1.4621914477994719`*^-25 + 
                x (2.861005887899597`*^-31 + 
                   x (-7.445111012247261`*^-38 + 
                    x (-1.1270416901426349`*^-43 + 
                    x (1.6123052698323394`*^-50 + 
                       (2.1652946572170675`*^-56 - 3.609271769434095`*^-66 x) x)))))))) // 
                          FullSimplify;

F[x_] = Piecewise[{
         {0, -10^10 < x < -12*10^5}, 
         {K[x], -12*10^5 <= x <= 12*10^5}, 
         {1, 12*10^5 < x}}];

S2best = 1.4971828497238327`*^6;
i = 1;

f[w_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := (A - a p) (p - w) + (1 - 
     F[-(A - a p) (w - i)])  (A - a i)^2/(4 a) + 
  F[-(A - a p) (w - i)] (  + ((i - j) (A - a i)/2 - (A - a j)^2/(8 a) ) + (A - 
         a i)^2/(4 a)      - b (A - a p) (p - w)  )

pR[w_?NumericQ] := Block[{p}, NArgMax[{f[w, p], p >= 0}, p]]
J[w_?NumericQ] := (A - a pR[w]) (w - i)
NMaximize[
   {J[w], {A/a > w > i, f[w, pR[w]] >= S2best}}, {w}, 
   Method -> {"RandomSearch", "SearchPoints" -> 3}, AccuracyGoal -> 2
]
```

However, comparing the result I get to `J[228]` and `f[228, pR[228]]` shows that there exists a better allowed optimum.

What method might return better results?

Comment: "What method might return better results?" - it really depends on what you are optimizing. It's difficult to say anything meaningful without seeing the function being optimized.

Comment: Hi J.M. thanks and i now added the code.